# Asyncsocket on iOS stuck at delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, asyncsocket

I am new to objective C, as a whole and iOS in particular, but i spent the last day to learn it.

i've been trying to create a simple app that reads data from a socket.
I understood that Asyncsocket is the best solution and have started working with it, but I encountered a problem.. it goes through all the delegates (connected to host, read data, disconnected) but then it drifts off and gets stuck somewhere.

heres the code:

```
- (void) connect:(NSString *)ip PORT:(NSInteger)port
{
    //open asyncsoket
    connectSocket  = [[AsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [connectSocket setDelegate:self];

    // open connection
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![connectSocket connectToHost:ip onPort:port error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error starting client: %@", error);
        return;
    }
}




- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port{
    // if connection was succeful read from socket
    NSLog(@"connected to server");
    [sock readDataWithTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];



}


- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag{

    //if did read data
    [connectSocket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];
    to_pass = data;
    [sock disconnect];

}


- (void)onSocketDidDisconnect:(AsyncSocket *)sock{
    // nothing to do

}

- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock willDisconnectWithError:(NSError *)err{
    //nothing to do
}
```

if i follow by break points it seems i goes through all those it needs, but then goes to assembly code and stops here:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap:
0x2178f70:  movl   $4294967265, %eax
0x2178f75:  calll  0x217f4bc                 ; _sysenter_trap
0x2178f7a:  ret    ----> right here 
0x2178f7b:  nop
```

Comment: In the debugger frame, do you see a stack trace? You can type `bt` to print it in the debugger.